# Glossary with term, translation, and page number (scrreprt)

Tags: glossaries, scrreprt

I'm writing a mathematical script in German (scrreprt). I want it to have a **glossary** which should contain:

1. the term,
2. its translation to English, and
3. the page number of the first occurrence of the term.

The glossary should start on a new page. The pages for the glossary should be devided into two coloumns (all the other pages not).
Is there any good way to do that (recommended packages, settings, macros etc.)?

Thank you so much for sharing your expertise!

Comment: Open your browser, type in `google.com`, enter the search terms `glossary latex`, and hit enter. Choose any of the first hits that appeals to you. One of them is e.g. [The glossaries package v4.46: a guide for beginners](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf).

Comment: In my personal experience, the guides to the `glossaries` packages are quite overwhelming. They tend to give way too much information about various settings you likely never use, while ignoring the basic stuff. Once you understand a little bit about how `glossaries` works, the guides make a lot more sense. But in order to get this experience, a simple example for a specific situation works best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style `mcolindex` in `glossaries` does exactly what you want.

Here is how it works:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[indexonlyfirst]{glossaries} % indexonlyfirst gives you only the first occurance
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}             % glossary-mcols to be able to set the style
\renewcommand{\glsmcols}{2}             % set the number of columns at 2
\setglossarystyle{mcolindex}            % set the style

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{1}{                   % this defines the terms
    name={term1},
    description={explanation of term 1}
}
\newglossaryentry{2}{
    name={term 2},
    description={explanation of term 2}
}
\begin{document}
    \gls{1} \gls{2}                     % these calls the terms
    \printglossary
\end{document}
```

Then you need to run latex, makeglossaries, latex, latex

This gives the following glossary:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! @cktai